# "X question/s with new activity" doesn't disappear after refreshing the question list

Tags: bug, android-app, question-lists

Before refreshing the page:

[image: This is the image taken before refreshing the page]

After refreshing the page:

[image: And this is after before refreshing the page.]

**The bug**:
The "X question/s with new activity" box keeps alive *after* refreshing when any question has got new activity.

*Android Kitkat, MiUi 7, SE App 1.0.77 (latest version).*